# Is there a way to hover in the mobile (Android) version of Microsoft Word?

Tags: mouse, microsoft-word

I have a .docx document with images that are animated when you hover over them. It works fine on my computer, but when I copied the file over to my phone, I cannot work out what to do to make them start.

Is it possible? And if so, what is the most simple way to do so?

Comment: I assume with hovering you mean "move the mouse cursor over the image". The main problem is that on mobile devices you have touch but not a mouse cursor. This might be a problem. The other potential problem is that the mobile versions of Office don't support all features of the desktop versions. I don't know which one of the two mentioned problems (or both) causes the missing animation.